# My website has some Crawling Errors?

Tags: urls

Hi my website has some crawling errors. Some url’s indexed in google like this” `http://www.movierola.com/shopbrand/ct554`.
why my website some urls indexed with /shopbrand/ct554. If any body knows please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be the case when you heave 'deadlinks' or broken links at one of your pages. You can try submitting a sitemap of your site. There are several plugins that can generate a sitemap for you. I can recommend Yoast SEO.

Then just submit your sitemap URL at Google Webmaster tools. You can also see some more Crawling statistics and diagnostics in here!

Then you should wait until Google has crawled all pages. Google can detect a 404 page and will remove it!